# my WD Mybook wd5000h0032 is DEAD?

Tags: hard-drive, repair, mybook

i have a WD Mybook Premium (wd5000h032) it used to work just fine but suddenly i can't access to it. The blue lights turn on but the drive doesn't start, it makes no click, nor any other sound, it just like if it was disconnected from USB, of course my PC doesn't detect it, i've tried with trhee different USB cables two PCs and one laptop and nothing.

Is it really dead? how can i recover the information stored there? i think the problem could be the case, if so, could i take out the disk and connect it as an internal drive? or could i buy another case?

Comment: Google results...https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=WD+Mybook+Premium+disassemble&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Answer (score 1):

Try this website. It may just be the conroller board on your external hard drive.

http://www.tested.com/how-to-take-apart-and-recover-faulty-external-hard-drive/47-104/

Comment: I find this to be the case more often than not.